# Jquery Toggle Two or More Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It is hard to explain what I try to do due to the limitation of my English. So just see the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mZV7R/1/

```
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( "."+$(this).attr('value') ).toggle();
});
```

When the Man check box is checked, then Man items are shown. When Man and Woman are both checked, then nothing should be shown.

How to do that?

I want to do something like a **AND** operation with CSS classes visibility. But the browser render engine seems to do a **OR** operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("input").on("click", function () {
    var selector = $('input[name="human"]:checked').map(function () {
        return '.' + this.value;
    }).get().join('')
    $('div').hide().filter(selector).show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4jT3M/)

---

To clean up

```
<input type="checkbox" name="human" value="man">Man<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="human" value="woman">Woman<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="human" value="tall">Tall<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="human" value="short">Short


<div class="human tall man">Tall Man</div>
<div class="human short man">Short Man</div>
<div class="human tall woman">Tall Woman</div>
<div class="human short woman">Short Woman</div>
```

then

```
var $humans = $('div.human');
$('input[name="human"]').on("click", function () {
    var selector = $('input[name="human"]:checked').map(function () {
        return '.' + this.value;
    }).get().join('')
    $humans.hide().filter(selector).show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bzk46/)

Comment: It worked. Can you explain how you achieve it? The logic behid it I mean.

Comment: @JamesKing The first step is to create a selector which will select only those elements that has to be displayed, so we iterate through all the checked inputs and create a selector like `.man.tall` or `.man.woman` then we hides all the divs and then displays only those elements that matches the given selector